# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'requests'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

Here are the errors I got when trying to test my Lambda function

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'requests'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "baef5cbe-c542-4ae0-9d3e-bda4ee80f0b9",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Here is also my python code

```
import requests
import os
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime

# https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api

# empire state building
lat = '40.75009231913161'
lon = '-73.98638285425646'
exclude = 'minutely,hourly,alerts'

url = (
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?' +
    'lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={exclude}&appid={API_key}&units=imperial'
)


if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()


def __send_email(msg: str) -> None:
    gmail_user = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')
    gmail_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

    # Create Email
    mail_from = gmail_user
    mail_to = gmail_user
    mail_subject = f'Weather Today {datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}'
    mail_message = f'Subject: {mail_subject}\n\n{msg}'

    # Send Email
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)
    server.close()


def handler(event, context):
    response = requests.get(url.format(
        lat=lat,
        lon=lon,
        exclude=exclude,
        API_key=os.getenv('WEATHER_API_KEY')
    ))

    data = response.json()

    rain_conditions = ['rain', 'thunderstorm', 'drizzle']
    snow_conditions = ['snow']

    today_weather = data['daily'][0]['weather'][0]['main'].lower()

    if today_weather in rain_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack an umbrella!'
    elif today_weather in snow_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack your snow boots!'
    else:
        msg = 'Clear skies today!'

    __send_email(msg)

handler(None, None)
```

One thing I noticed is that lambda says it supports up to python version 3.9 and my code was written using 3.10.2, is that a possible reason for this error? The runtime is set to 3.9 and I tried switching it to 3.7 and 3.8 and I just get different errors, but I'm unable to do 3.10.2

Should I just create a docker container and run it on there? Would that help solve my issue or is it just something wrong with my code?

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bundle `requests` library with your application. [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/) explain in details how to do it.

You have to do it for every dependency of your lambda, or use [lambda containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) if you have lots of dependencies.